# Class Interceptor error

Tags: catalogsearch, plugin, interceptor

I have developed a module that use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection
but when I call the method i get this error:

```
Error occurred when creating object: Oct\Oct\Helper\Search\Magento, Argument 10 passed to 
Oct\Oct\Helper\Search\Magento::__construct() must be an instance of 
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection, instance of 
WeltPixel\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor given.
```

is it an override? can you skip this to use the original class?

Thnk!

Comment: Does your class extend the original?

Comment: WeltPixel is a ThirdParty module that has an interceptor to Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection

Comment: I want to prevent that interceptor.

Comment: I think we might need to see more of the code to be of assistance

Comment: `WeltPixel\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection` and `Oct\Oct\Helper\Search\Magento`  share the code of this two files. Also specify your magento version

Comment: Magento 2 (All versions)

Comment: The problem is I have inejcting the class Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection to my method, but i am receiving WeltPixel\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection.

Comment: I think that Weltpixel have a interceptor around Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection